# ios escape '<' from string inside html tag - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, html-escape-characters

I have following HTML string which is generating gynamically from local db :

```
<div><span>If x < 20 Then y > 20 </span><div> //NSString : dynamically generated
```

What should be done to escape '<' and '>' symbol from string inside html tags so that we would get following output :

```
<div><span>If x &lt; 20 Then y &gt; 20 </span><div>
```

**Update**

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<td style=\"vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 95%;\">\
    <span>$$If\\ \\ f(x) \\ \\ is \\ continuous \\ on \\ [0,8]\\ defined \\ as$$<br>\
    $$f(x) = x^2 +ax + 6 \\ \\ \\ \\ for \\ \\ 0 <x < 2$$<br>\
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $$= 3x +2 \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ for \\ 2<x<4$$<br>\
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $$= 2ax + 5b \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ for \\ 2<x<8$$<br>\
                Find <em>a</em>&nbsp;and <em>b</em></span>\
    </td>";
```

This whole string is generated dynamically and I want any '<' and '>' except those with HTML entities to be escaped. This is requirement for rendering mathematical expression in UIWebView using MathJax.

Comment: try using a html parser.

Comment: plz have a look at my update in question. Does html parser play well for dynamic html string ?

Comment: yes, it will work for dynamically generated html too

Comment: Thanx ! Any working example or reference link ??

Comment: just do a google search on ios html parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *) replaceHTMLEntitiesInString:(NSString *) htmlString {
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@" "];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"];
    return htmlString;
}
```

Call as `htmlString = [self replaceHTMLEntitiesInString:htmlString];`

Comment: This would be applied to html entities as well. So it will return :  **&lt;div&gt;&lt;span&gt;If x &lt; 20 Then y &gt; 20 &lt;/span&gt;&lt;div&gt;**